# Print exit order of child processes

Tags: c, process, fork, pid

I have this code. My aim is to create 'n' child processes from parent process and print the pid of each child processes once it is created.

Then I'll ask each child process to sleep for random duration using `rand_r` function and `exit`. I want to print the exit order of child processes *i.e* I want to print their pids in their exit order.

This is my C code. It is not giving required output:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int func(int n) 
{
    if(n==0){return 0;}
    int pid=fork();

    unsigned int k=n;
    int x=rand_r(&k) % 3;
    //printf("here: %d\n", x);

    if(pid==0){
        printf("Child %d is created\n",getpid());
        func(n-1);
        sleep(x);
        printf("Child %d exited\n",getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *inp = argv[1];
    int n = atoi(inp);
    func(n);

    return 0;
}
```

I want output like this:

```
Child 7432 is created 
Child 7433 is created 
Child 7434 is created 
Child 7435 is created   
Child 7433 exited 
Child 7432 exited 
Child 7435 exited 
Child 7434 exited
```

Comment: What output are you getting? How do you know what the right exit order is without printing `x`?

Comment: where do you `wait()` ?

Comment: I am getting required statements but they are NOT in right order. I mean, first I want to get list of all created child processes and after that I want to get list of excited processes.

Comment: Then you should a) not have a recursive `func()` but start child processes in a loop and store child PIDs in an array b) call `wait()` until all child processes have exited

Comment: Isn't it possible to make small changes to my code. Should I change it completely?

Comment: At the moment you *don't* "create 'n' child processes from parent process"

Comment: yes you should. Recursion is not what you should do here